# applications of algebraic geometry in topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have just been introduced to Algebraic Geometry and find it to be very interesting.I like the abstraction of concepts and it just makes me realise the beauty of mathematics as a subject. So when I specifically look at the interplay of algebraic geometry with any other field, I am not completely satisfied with how much I have understood. I did try watching a couple of videos and read few pages on google, but I would like someone to explain the answer to my questions in a simple yet detailed manner.
So my questions are:
(1) How are the abstractions involved in algebraic geometry helping mathematicians to understand other unanswered or not-so-clear concepts better? Please give me examples of concepts that are better understood with algebraic geometry in mind.
(2) How did the subject originate?
(3) How far has this subject been studied and What are the various directions in which research in this area is progressing?
 I am just a beginner when it comes to Algebraic Geometry .So It would be nice if the explanations are understandable to a novice .I am really interested in the subject and would like to know more to pursue study in this direction further.
Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a good question, but very, very broad.  You might be better off asking for a few references to accessible books on the subject.  Joe Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course* might be good for you.

Comment: A book for *much* later would be Hirzebruch's "Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry" for some of the deeper connections to topology.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting the reference books! I shall surely look into them! Could you probably suggest papers or pdf articles that I could read just to give me an insight into what sort of applications are out there before i dive into an in-depth reading as in the above books?